# How to provide a custom input method in a QML application?

Tags: qt, qml

I read the documentation about [Adding Input Method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtvirtualkeyboard-overview.html) to Virtualkeyboard Plugins but do not quite understand how I actually implement the input method.

I tried this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: window

    width: 200
    height: 100

    visible: true

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: window
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel

        z: 99
        x: 0
        y: window.height

        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }

        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }

    InputMethod {
        id: myInputMethod

        function inputModes(locale) {
            return [InputEngine.Latin]
        }

        function setInputMode(locale, inputMode) {
            return true
        }

        function setTextCase(textCase) {
            return true
        }

        function reset() {}

        function update() {}

        function keyEvent(key, text, modifiers) {
            return true
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: InputContext.inputEngine.inputMethod = myInputMethod
}
```

But already this basic example fails. The problem is that, whenever the TextField attains focus, e.g. when I click on it, the application crashes immediately.

(Background is that I want to provide a custom input method that would provide custom selection lists to (text) input fields as sort of auto-completion feature via the VirtualKeyboard facility.)

...the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(inputMethod VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

qt_add_executable(appinputMethod
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appinputMethod
    URI inputMethod
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(appinputMethod PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.appinputMethod
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appinputMethod
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS appinputMethod
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

Comment: Show your cmake o qmake file

Comment: There is nothing special about the cmake file. I actually didn't edit it at all. It's straight from what you get with Qt Creator if you create a new project with virtual keyboard support.

Comment: Component.onCompleted: InputContext.inputEngine.inputMethod = myInputMethod

This line probably won't work; inputEngine is read-only.

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html#building-with-cmake

Comment: You must add the VirtualKeyboard component in CmakeLists.txt

Comment: Use this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html

Comment: @mzimmers This is actually the recommended way to assign an input method according to the documentation. Your are correct, in every other occurrence the input method property is indeed read-only, e.g. Qt.inputMethod, but here it is not!

Comment: @eyllanesc: Adding VirtualKeyboard component to the CMakeLists.txt doesn't change anything. I tested this before. It is not a linkage or compilation problem. The application crashes with a segmentation fault. - I also searched the documentation and the internet. I could not find a working example of how to assign the input method. A look at the source code reveals that providing a QML type named "DefaultInputMethod" located in the VirtualKeyboard "namespace" should work. But I do not know how to create such a type within the QML type hierarchy at the proper location.